# How to get media manager file attribute (CREATED DATE) in Joomla! 3.10.5

Tags: joomla

I would like to ask you if there is any way to get the uploaded (created date) of each file as attribute in the media manager regarding Joomla! 3.10.5 via specific grid column.

That would help me a lot!

Regards